# How to specify dependency_overrides in pubspec.yaml?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am working with latest version of angular.dart and my `pubspec.yaml` looks somewhat like this:

```
name: angularApp
dependencies:
  angular:
    git:  'git@github.com:angular/angular.dart'
  third_party_angular_plugin: any
```

the problem is `third_party_angular_plugin` is depending on stable version of `angular.dart`. I tried to specify as follows:

```
name: angularApp
dependencies:
  angular:
    git:  'git@github.com:angular/angular.dart'
  third_party_angular_plugin: any
dependency_overrides:
  angular:
    version: ">=0.9.10"
```

But it throws a weird error saying `Bad State: No elements dart:core List.single ....`

How can I override `third_party_angular_plugin`'s dependency on angular for my app?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `version` is not a separate nested key, as per the example on [Pub Dependencies](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html) page, the right format is this:

```
name: angularApp
dependencies:
  angular:
    git:  'git@github.com:angular/angular.dart'
  third_party_angular_plugin: any
dependency_overrides:
  angular: ">=0.9.10"
```

Comment: Don't you have that reversed?  The override would typically be the local copy.