# Flutter integration_test package conflict with my code and cannot be resolved by tweaking package versions - so the whole app cannot run

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, pubspec

I have an app (with null-safety), and want to use integration_test package to do some testing. The pubspec.yaml looks like:

```
dependencies:
  archive: ^3.1.2
  ...

dev_dependencies:
  build_resolvers: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^1.11.5
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  ...
```

Then it errors:

```
Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on archive 2.0.13 and my_app depends on archive ^3.1.2, flutter_driver from sdk is forbidden.
```

I **cannot** use the non-null-safety version (2.x) of archive package, because if I do so, my app code will fail to run in null safety mode! I can accept that my *tests* run in non-null-safety mode, but I cannot tolerate my *app code* run in non-null-safety mode.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You need to override the archive version. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031384/how-to-specify-dependency-overrides-in-pubspec-yaml . I'm also not sure why the flutter_driver is depending on an old version of archive. Are using the latest flutter sdk version?

Comment: @Uni imho because flutter driver is not null safe?

Comment: @Uni on the other hand, dependency_overrides is quite unsafe :( can I use it without any fear?

Comment: @Uni I (possibly) solved this problem using dependency_overrides. Not sure whether there will be hidden issues, but looks ok currently. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it was able to help you. Unfortunately, dependency_override is **generally** unsafe but it is **safe** in your scenario because it is only being used for testing.  Errors would only occur during testing and not when the user is using the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `archive` package version to tell `flutter_driver` to use the latest one:

```
dev_dependencies:
  build_resolvers: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^1.11.5
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
dependency_overrides:
  archive: ">=3.1.2"
```