# error after update flutter sdk and all packages

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an app that has been worked  in flutter sdk flutter 1.22.3
but I  update to flutter 2.2.3 and updating all  packages

error

```
C:\src\sdk\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in app...                             

Because rounded_loading_button >=2.0.3 depends on rxdart ^0.26.0 and app depends on rxdart ^0.27.1, rounded_loading_button >=2.0.3 is forbidden.
So, because app depends on rounded_loading_button ^2.0.5, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because app depends on rounded_loading_button ^2.0.5, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

How can I solve this problem, I have been trying for more than a week, please help
```

Answer (score 1):

You have conflicting dependencies either:

1. lower the rxdart version if you can in your app's to be compatible with `rounded_loading_button` (lower it to rxdart ^0.26.0).
2. Fork `rounded_loading_button` and update the rxdart version (^0.27.1 or higher)(and preferably make a PR to the author)
3. you could try to use a [dependency_override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031384/how-to-specify-dependency-overrides-in-pubspec-yaml)

Comment: this work 
rxdart: ^0.27.1
rounded_loading_button: any

but some erorr for this

Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on meta 1.3.0 and json_annotation >=4.1.0 depends on meta ^1.4.0, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with json_annotation >=4.1.0.